# EventGrid Webhook Scenario

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-eventgrid

Team -

From the [documentation provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/receive-events#handle-custom-events) it is clear that if you are using a webhook handler, in success scenarios you need to return 200 OK. But if I am not wrong the collection of events is posted to the webhook and not a single event - so are we saying 200 OK is to be returned inside for loop instead of outside? I mean what happens if out of 3 events received 1 fails and 2 passes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (api-version=2018-05-01-preview) subscribers received only a single event in the array (JArray) for DeliverySchema such as the *EventGridSchema* and *InputEventSchema*. Note, that the array is used for possible option in the future for delivering a batch of the events to the subscriber.

On the other side, the new delivery schema such as a *CloudEventV01Schema* allows to post only a single event to the subscriber (JObject).